# Start Activity from Fragment return Error

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have a fragment and activity with gridview inside it. It start the fragment acticity first. And there is button inside fragment that will open or start the gridview activity. There is no red line in my code, so i run the project. But when i open the button on fragment it return error or crash.

It says

> "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo(EpicList):  java.lang.NullPointetException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference"

.

Here is all the code

//Fragment

BundleEpic.java

```
public class BundleEpic extends Fragment {


    public BundleEpic() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_bundleepic, container, false);

        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EpicList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

//BasicActivity with Gridview

EpicList.java

```
  public class EpicList extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_bundleepic);

            GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);

            List<EpicListItem> epicListItems = getEpicListItemList();
            EpicListAdapter epicListAdapter = new EpicListAdapter(EpicList.this, epicListItems);
            gridView.setAdapter(epicListAdapter);

            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                    final Intent intent;
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            intent = new Intent(EpicList.this, MainActivity.class);
                            break;

                        default:
                            intent = new Intent(EpicList.this, MainActivity.class);
                            break;
                    }
                    EpicList.this.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }


        private List<EpicListItem> getEpicListItemList() {
            EpicListItem epicListItem = null;
            List<EpicListItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
            items.add(new EpicListItem(R.drawable.border_epic));

            return items;
        }
    }
```

EpicListAdapter

```
public class EpicListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<EpicListItem> epicListItems;
    private Context context;

    public EpicListAdapter(Context context, List<EpicListItem> customizeListView) {
        this.context = context;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        epicListItems = customizeListView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return epicListItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder listViewHoler;
        if (convertView == null) {
            listViewHoler = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_epic_item, parent, false);
            listViewHoler.imageInListView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            convertView.setTag(listViewHoler);
        } else {
            listViewHoler = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        listViewHoler.imageInListView.setImageResource(epicListItems.get(position).getImageResource());

        return convertView;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageInListView;
    }

}
```

EpicListItem.java

```
public class EpicListItem {

    private int imageResource;

    public EpicListItem(int imageResource) {
        this.imageResource = imageResource;
    }
    public int getImageResource() {
        return imageResource;
    }

    public void setImageResource(int imageResource) {
        this.imageResource = imageResource;
    }
}
```

activity_epic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".EpicList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_epic_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="3dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Jens can you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, it cant set the adapter of null.

This is probably because you are trying to find a view using `findViewById(int id)`, where the layout hasn't been inflated yet.

Comment: The id is match, take a look at my activity_epic.xml

Comment: Then, your layout hasn't been inflated yet.

Comment: Oh wait, i think i put wrong layout on my EpicList.java

Comment: @user9921322 No Problem :)